# Download all files or folders from Web URI in C# .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have a webserver that if you open up the URI in the browser it shows a similar page to https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/other/HLSQA2/ (this is just an example that i found on web)
[image: WebServerExample]

Is it possible in C# .NET 6 to download all the files that are in here? And by that i mean all files or folders with everything in it, even if there are subfolders in there.

About a GET request I get only html data...

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It matters. HTTP isn't a file transfer protocol. What gets returned when you issue a GET is *entirely* up to the server. Traditional web servers can be configured to return the contents of a folder. You'll have to write a web crawler that understands what the server returns and follow the links

Comment: On the other hand, S3 and similar services have no folders. These are emulated using special characters like `/` in the URL. In that case you can use the service's API to retrieve a list of all files.

Comment: `I have a webserver`  did you check its configuration? Perhaps it can be configured to return the full file list, perhaps not. This isn't a C# issue

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in C# .NET 6 to download all the files that are in
> here? And by that i mean all files or folders with everything in it,
> even if there are subfolders in there.

Well, if you are saying from browser (client-side), you want to download all folder along with sub-folder and files into it then no there's so such way to download all the containing folders and file together from a specific URL. It's not about only .NET 6 or regardless of any version.

But you can set a download button beside your folder and when the user would click on the button it would download all the files inside the folder.

What it would do within the controller is, you will pass the folder name, and by the folder name we will get the path using `Path.GetFullPath`.

Once we get the path, we can fetch all the files from the specified folder and will get the file as byte array using `MemoryStream` and at the same time we have to create zip entry by using [`ZipArchive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)

Finally, we can make a byte array of all the files and return a zip file along with all the files.

Let's have a look in practice, how we can implement that:

Download All Files From Folder As Zip:

I have a following folder which I want to download:

[image]

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DownLoadAll()
        {

            var folderPath = Path.GetFullPath("./wwwroot/ImageName/Cover/");

            // Make sure the folder exists
            if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
                return NotFound("Folder has not found.");

            // Getting list of files in the folder
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

            if (files.Length == 0)
                return NotFound("No files has founded to download.");

            // Creating a temporary memory stream to hold the zip archive
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create a new zip archive
                using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach (var file in files)
                    {
                        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                        // Create a new entry in the zip archive for each file
                        var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileInfo.Name);

                        // Write the file contents into the entry
                        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }

                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Finally return the zip file as a byte array into zip folder
                var zipFileName = $"DownloadedFiles-{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")}.zip";
                return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipFileName);
                
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official doccument for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files).